# With psycopg2, how to insert a NULL value to a db using an SQL command with string literals

Tags: psycopg2

Here is a Python expression using the psycopg2 library:

```
if 'address' in data:
    address = data['address']
else:
    address = None

cursor.execute(f"UPDATE public.mytable SET name = '{name}', address = '{address}' WHERE id = '{my_id}')
```

Oddly when the address variable is set to None, it inserts a 'None' string into the address column, instead of inserting a null value.

There doesn't seem to be any explanation for this behavior in the psycopg2 documentation. Is there any method to insert a null value instead of a 'None' string in a database?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment you should per [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) do:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE public.mytable SET name = %s, address = %s WHERE id = %s", 
[name, address, my_id])
```

or

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE public.mytable SET name = %(name_val)s, address = %(address_val)s WHERE id = %(id_val)s", 
{"name_val": name, "address_val": address, "id_val": my_id])
```